# Weird / Wrong outpout of np.argsort()

Tags: python, numpy

I was working with numpy and argsort, while encountering a *strange (?)* behavior of argsort:

```
>>> array = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
             [444, 4, 8, 3, 1, 10], 
             [2, 5, 8, 999, 1, 4]]
>>> np.argsort(array, axis=0)

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

The first 4 values of each list are pretty clear to me - `argsort` doing it's job right. But the last 2 values are pretty confusing, as it is kinda sorting the values wrong.
Shouldn't the output of `argsort` be:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: No, you are sorting columns individually into ascending order. The result seems fine. Take `a[:, 4][[1, 2, 0]]` vs  `a[:, 4][[2, 0, 1]]`. Your version would put the 4 in the middle of the column (index 0), instead of the end.

Comment: Were you thinking of the inverse operation perhaps?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand your comment right..
Yes, by specifying the axis as 0, it should sort them by columns. So take the first values, for example. -> Sorting 0, 444 and 2, which would be 0, 2, 1 - which is then put into index 0 of the three lists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue is with what you think `argsort` is outputting. Let's focus on a simpler 1D example:

```
 arr = np.array([5, 10, 4])
```

The result of `np.argsort` will be the indices from the original array to make the elements sorted:

```
[2, 0, 1]
```

Let's take a look at what the actual sorted values are to understand why:

```
[
     4,  # at index 2 in the original array
     5,  # at index 0 in the original array
    10,  # at index 1 in the original array
]
```

It seems like you are imagining the inverse operation, where `argsort` will tell you what index in the output each element will move to. You can obtain those indices by applying `argsort` to the result of `argsort`.

Comment: @Henning your comment to the other answer finally made me understand what you were thinking. I've been there myself :)

Comment: yeah, the inverse operation is what I wanted, thank you @Mad Physicist :)

Comment: @Henning. It blew my mind the first time I realized argsort is it's own inverse

Comment: I know this is and old answer, but for god's sake it's really useful. I'm learning Python and this answer made my day. Now I understand how it works! One million thanks!

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns. Always happy to make someone happy :)

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct, the thing is that np.argsort with axis=0, is actually comparing the each element of the first axis elements'. So, that for array

```
array = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
...      [444, 4, 8, 3, 1, 10], 
...      [2, 5, 8, 999, 1, 4]]
```

axis=0, compares the elements, (0, 444, 2), (1,4,8), (2,8,8), (3,3,999), (4,1,1), (5,10,4) so that it gives the array of indices as:

```
np.argsort(array, axis=0)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1]])
```

So, for your question the last 2 values, comes from the elements (4,1,1) which give the array index value as (1,2,0), and for (5,10,4) it gives (2,0,1).

Refer this: [np.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

Comment: Yeah, I understand that it compares them column wise. But shouldn't (5, 10, 4) give (1, 2, 0) as 5 < 10 and 4 < 5?